# SQL relationship for database of Property/Estates

Tags: sql, relationship, relation

### I need to help with school project and Iam starting to being really desperate.

Assignment was ->

### Create SQL database with relations for Property evidention(It must be able to properly register Propertys - Tenants, Repairs, Costs, etc...)

---

I made relations like this:
[Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFJYT.png)

---

**Teacher said that mine design of relations is extremly bad, and this was the reasons:**

1)Tenant must be able to have more than 1 property (So switch Tenants and Propertys)

2)He said I should add table for Cost Category

3)He also said that I should redesign table with Costs ->that there should be Cost and PropertyID(Cost category)???? - I dont know if I uderstanded correctly about this one.

4) He said that I should delete Cost table

5) He wondered why I have RepairPrice in 2 tables

---

We need to use Microsoft SQL server

Can someone show me how proper relation sheme should look like?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like Properties should be a child table of tenants, i.e. remove the property id from the tenants table, make the property table have a FK relation to the property table. Sounds like instead of the Cost table, you should simply have a cost column in the repair table.

Comment: I thank that he said that I shoudl have table TypeofCost and Cost and delete repair table... would that be suitable? So there would be 4 tables: Tentants,Properties,TypeofCost and Cost